# How to read a Json file in jQuery

Tags: json

I'm using VS2012, and running an ASP.NET MVC4 project.

I cannot seem to get this to fire below :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "~/xml/JsonTest.json",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (json) {
        alert("HI");                
    }
});
```

I also tried it this way , but to no avail :

```
$.getJSON('../xml/JsonTest.json', function (json) {            
        alert("GET JSON !");
    });
```

Is it somehow not finding the directory structure ?
thanks.
Bob

Comment: please check if this helps: http://iviewsource.com/codingtutorials/getting-started-with-javascript-object-notation-json-for-absolute-beginners/

Answer (score 2):

The first one definitely won't work, since `~` doesn't mean anything client-side.  What actual URL is requested by the second example?  Does it send an AJAX request at all?  What is the response?

If you have a dynamic server-side URL then you'll want to use server-side code to dynamically build it in the rendered output.  Something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Content("~/xml/JsonTest.json")',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (json) {
        alert("HI");                
    }
});
```

This would result in the client-side JavaScript being rendered with the full URL for the server-side path `"~/xml/JsonTest.json"`.

Comment: nothing gets fired on the second $.getJSON() request ! I've tried several ways...

Comment: @bob: How do you validate the AJAX requests/responses?  In any event, what is the request/response for the AJAX call if you use the server-side URL helper in my answer?

Comment: I have no problems calling into my controller as in url: "/Margins/getInitMargin". But to grab a physical file ? Not working !

Comment: Ooh at least I got an error when trying to @Url idea: "The relative virtual path '~xml/JsonTest.json' is not allowed here."

Comment: using f12 dev tools in IE, ">HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found". "The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration"

Comment: @bob: You may have a typo in there, it's `~/xml` not `~xml`.  If the former also fails, then that gives you something to investigate.  Find out why that path isn't allowed.  Also, what happens if you hard-code the *full* (not relative) URL to the file in the AJAX call just for testing?  What happens if you enter the full URL manually into your web browser and request the file?  If the server is refusing to serve the contents of that file then the problem isn't in your JavaScript.

Comment: I've been also working on the c# method to load that json file and deserialize it into a c# class. I'm getting "invalid json primitive" errors when reading from a file. When hard coding the same exact Json and assigning to a local var, it works fine and deserializes perfectly. Go figure. http://forums.asp.net/p/1920216/5447868.aspx/1?Help+to+deserialize+Json+data+to+a+C+class

Comment: thanks but I do have it as ~/xml. I've tried several ways. And it appears to be a mime-type related issue where .net won't let me access the file directly.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution for my case was to properly code it up in a C# method as follows :

```
   public string getJsonParameters()
    {

        JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        string jsonStr = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/myKeys.json"));                        

        JsonParameters jsonData = (JsonParameters)ser.Deserialize(jsonStr, typeof(JsonParameters));            

        return  jsonStr;
    }
```